# Is it $\mu(dx)$ or $d\mu(x)$? or they are equal?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In probability theory, I have seen two forms of an integral. Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure and $f$ is a function.

> What is the difference between the following two forms:
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) \mu(dx)
> \end{eqnarray}
> and
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) d\mu(x)
> \end{eqnarray}

Please give some references for your answer.

Comment: They are the same thing

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133570/why-is-the-notation-mudt-in-integrals-so-widely-used-in-general-measure-the

Comment: @ZacharySelk, Could you please provide a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the other answers didn't provide a reference and you asked for one in the comments, a reference can be found in Schillings Measures Integrals and Martingales (ISBN 9780521615259), Page 77. There they state:
In case we need to exhibit the integration variable, we write
$$
\int u d \mu=\int u(x) \mu(d x)=\int u(x) d \mu(x)
$$

Note that for a distribution of a random variable:
$$\mathbb P_X(A)= \mathbb P ( X \in A)$$
Schilling also writes
$$\int u(X(\omega)) \mathbb P(d \omega)= \int u(s) \mathbb P (X \in ds)$$
for suitable function $u$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by saying that unfortunately I have no references at hand.

---

Both are notations for the same thing: the integral of function $f$ with respect to measure $\mu$.

Which to use is a matter of taste.

Personally I prefer: $$\cdots\mu(dx)$$ because somehow a measurement of the infinitesimal small $dx$ takes place.

In the special case where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ you could say that we have the equality: $$\lambda(dx)=dx$$

i.e. the measure of $dx$ equals $dx$ itself.

If $\mu$ is also a measure on $\mathbb R$ and this with a density $f$ wrt the Lebesgue measure then we can state:$$\mu(dx)=f(x)\lambda(dx)=f(x)dx$$

Comment: My analysis prof preferred compact forms, like writing $\int f$ instead of $\int f(x) \, dx$ (so that he could avoid questions like what does this '$dx$' precisely mean), and with an arbitrary measure he used $\int f\, d\mu$. Now if we want to write an expression of $x$ in place of $f$, we simply put $(x) $ at the end of $d\mu$ to indicate the bound variable.

Comment: @Berci Yes. There are arguments for the other side as well, as you showed. Personally I like writing the compact form $\mu(f)$ - looking at $\mu$ as a function on functions instead of a function on sets.

Comment: @drhab, Thank you for your answer. But please help me how to find a reference.

Comment: I only know one way to find references: exploring the internet which is for you the same as for me of course. Why exactly are you interested in references?

Comment: @drhab, I searched extensively the internet, but I didn't find anything. I need since someone forces me to prove that both notations are correct.

Comment: Both notations are in use and commonly accepted. That is enough for a notation. A mathematical proof of that cannot be given. At most you can argue about (dis)advantages.

Comment: Btw, "someone forces me.." Really? Don't allow that!

Comment: In the last line by density I think you mean that $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda.$ Right?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa I was just thinking of a nonnegative Borel-measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$. It induces a measure $\mu$ that is prescribed by $A\mapsto\int_Af(x)dx$. According to that I would rather say that $\mu$ is derived from $f$ and not so much that $f$ is derivative of $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\mu(dx)$ notation is convenient in stochastic processes. If $X$ is a (for simplicity time-homogeneous) Markov process, then instead of a transition matrix (as in Markov chains) one uses transition functions.

Ignoring some technical measurability conditions, a transition function is defined by the property $$\mathbb{P}(X_t \in A \mid X_s = x) = \int_A P_t(x, dy)$$
Here we assume that $P_t(x, \cdot)$ is a probability measure. The formula above means that if $\mu = P_t(x, \cdot)$, then
$$\mathbb{P}(X_t \in A \mid X_s = x) = \int_A \mu(dy)$$

It would be really clumsy to write 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_t \in A \mid X_s = x) = \int_A dP_t(x, \cdot)$$